# How to use a regex to search backwards effectively?

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching forward in an array of strings with a regex, like this:

```
for (int j = line; j < lines.length; j++) {  
    if (lines[j] == null || lines[j].isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }
    matcher = pattern.matcher(lines[j]);
    if (matcher.find(offset)) {
        offset = matcher.end();
        line = j;
        System.out.println("found \""+matcher.group()+"\" at line "+line+" ["+matcher.start()+","+offset+"]");
        return true;
    }
    offset = 0;
}
return false;
```

Note that in my implementation above I save the `line` and `offset` for continuous searches.

Anyway, now I want to **search backwards** from that [line,offset].

#### My question: is there a way to search backwards with a regex efficiently? if not, what could be an alternative?

**Clarification:** By *backwards* I mean finding the previous match.
For example, say that I'm searching for "dana" in

```
"dana nama? dana kama! lama dana kama?"
```

and got to the 2nd match. If I do `matcher.find()` again, I'll search *forward* and get the 3rd match. But I want to search *backwards* and get to the 1st match.
the code above should then output something like:

```
found "dana" at line 0 [0,3] // fwd
found "dana" at line 0 [11,14] // fwd
found "dana" at line 0 [0,3] // bwd
```

Comment: What do you mean with search backward being efficient?
You could make this function work recursivly and it won't be very inefficient then imo.

Comment: By backwards do you mean right to left [like Arabic]? .net supports it. For java I guess you can reverse string and match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's regular expression engine cannot search backwards.  In fact, the only regex engine that I know that can do that is the one in .NET.

Instead of searching backwards, iterate over all the matches in a loop (searching forward).  If the match is prior to the position you want, remember it.  If the match is after the position you want, exit from the loop.  In pseudo code (my Java is a little rusty):

```
storedmatch = ""
while matcher.find {
  if matcher.end < offset {
    storedmatch = matcher.group()
  } else {
    return storedmatch
  }
}
```

Comment: um... (?<=...) search backwards for any three characters. Yes it's 0 width but is does do lookbehind.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: Java's lookbehind is fixed-width.  You can use `(?<=abc)` to check 3 characters prior, but you cannot use `(?<=\w+)` to check any number of characters prior, nor can you use it for a backwards search.  If `(?<=...)` is your entire regex, it finds the position after the first 3 characters in the string, not the last 3 characters in the string.  In .NET, you can use `(?<=\w+)` and you can even use \w+ to search backwards to find the last word in a string by setting `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`.

Answer (score 6):

The following class search backward and forward (of course).

I used this class in an application where the users can search strings in a long text (like search feature in a Web browser). So it's tested and works well for practical use cases.

It uses an approach similar to what Jan Goyvaerts describes. It selects a block of text before the start position and searches it forwards, returning the last match if there is one. If there is no match if selects a new block of text before the of block and searches that in the same way.

Use it like this:

```
Search s = new Search("Big long text here to be searched [...]");
s.setPattern("some regexp");

// search backwards or forward as many times as you like,
// the class keeps track where the last match was
MatchResult where = s.searchBackward();
where = s.searchBackward(); // next match
where = s.searchBackward(); // next match

//or search forward
where = s.searchForward();
where = s.searchForward();
```

And the class:

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/*
 * Search regular expressions or simple text forward and backward in a CharSequence
 *
 * 
 * To simulate the backward search (that Java class doesn't have) the input data
 * is divided into chunks and each chunk is searched from last to first until a 
 * match is found (inter-chunk matches are returned from last to first too).
 *
 * The search can fail if the pattern/match you look for is longer than the chunk
 * size, but you can set the chunk size to a sensible size depending on the specific
 * application.
 *
 * Also, because the match could span between two adjacent chunks, the chunks are
 * partially overlapping. Again, this overlapping size should be set to a sensible
 * size.
 *
 * A typical application where the user search for some words in a document will
 * work perfectly fine with default values. The matches are expected to be between
 * 10-15 chars, so any chunk size and overlapping size bigger than this expected 
 * length will be fine.
 *
 * */
public class Search {

    private int BACKWARD_BLOCK_SIZE = 200;
    private int BACKWARD_OVERLAPPING = 20;

    private Matcher myFwdMatcher;
    private Matcher myBkwMatcher;
    private String  mySearchPattern;
    private int myCurrOffset;
    private boolean myRegexp;
    private CharSequence mySearchData;

    public Search(CharSequence searchData) {
        mySearchData = searchData;
        mySearchPattern = "";
        myCurrOffset = 0;
        myRegexp = true;
        clear();
    }

    public void clear() {
        myFwdMatcher = null;
        myBkwMatcher = null;
    }

    public String getPattern() {
        return mySearchPattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(String toSearch) {
        if ( !mySearchPattern.equals(toSearch) ) {
            mySearchPattern = toSearch;
            clear();
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return mySearchData;
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence searchData) {
        mySearchData = searchData;
        clear();
    }

    public void setSearchOffset(int startOffset) {
        if (myCurrOffset != startOffset) {
            myCurrOffset = startOffset;
            clear();
        }
    }

    public boolean isRegexp() {
        return myRegexp;
    }

    public void setRegexp(boolean regexp) {
        if (myRegexp != regexp) {
            myRegexp = regexp;
            clear();
        }
    }

    public MatchResult searchForward() {

        if (mySearchData != null) {

            boolean found;

            if (myFwdMatcher == null)
            {
                // if it's a new search, start from beginning
                String searchPattern = myRegexp ? mySearchPattern : Pattern.quote(mySearchPattern);
                myFwdMatcher = Pattern.compile(searchPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(mySearchData);
                try {
                    found = myFwdMatcher.find(myCurrOffset);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    found = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // continue searching
                found = myFwdMatcher.hitEnd() ? false : myFwdMatcher.find();
            }

            if (found) {
                MatchResult result = myFwdMatcher.toMatchResult();
                return onMatchResult(result);
            }
        }
        return onMatchResult(null);
    }

    public MatchResult searchBackward() {

        if (mySearchData != null) {

            myFwdMatcher = null;

            if (myBkwMatcher == null)
            {
                // if it's a new search, create a new matcher
                String searchPattern = myRegexp ? mySearchPattern : Pattern.quote(mySearchPattern);
                myBkwMatcher = Pattern.compile(searchPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(mySearchData);
            }

            MatchResult result = null;
            boolean startOfInput = false;
            int start = myCurrOffset;
            int end = start;

            while (result == null && !startOfInput)
            {
                start -= BACKWARD_BLOCK_SIZE;
                if (start < 0) {
                    start = 0;
                    startOfInput = true;
                }
                try {
                    myBkwMatcher.region(start, end);
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    break;
                }
                while ( myBkwMatcher.find() ) {
                    result = myBkwMatcher.toMatchResult();
                }
                end = start + BACKWARD_OVERLAPPING; // depending on the size of the pattern this could not be enough
                                                    //but how can you know the size of a regexp match beforehand?
            }

            return onMatchResult(result);
        }
        return onMatchResult(null);
    }

    private MatchResult onMatchResult(MatchResult result) {
        if (result != null) {
            myCurrOffset = result.start();    
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And if you like to test the class here is an usage example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class SearchTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    protected JScrollPane scrollPane;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    protected boolean docChanged = true;
    protected Search searcher;

    public SearchTest() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        searcher = new Search("");

        JButton backButton = new JButton("Search backward");
        JButton fwdButton  = new JButton("Search forward");

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(fwdButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        buttonPanel.add(backButton, BorderLayout.WEST); 

        textArea = new JTextArea("Big long text here to be searched...", 20, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Add actions
        backButton.setActionCommand("back");
        fwdButton.setActionCommand("fwd");
        backButton.addActionListener(this);
        fwdButton.addActionListener(this);

        textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final String pattern = textField.getText();
                searcher.setPattern(pattern);
            }
        } );

        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener( new DocumentListener() { 
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { docChanged = true; }
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { docChanged = true; }
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { docChanged = true; }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

        if ( docChanged ) {
            final String newDocument = textArea.getText();
            searcher.setText(newDocument);
            docChanged = false;
        }

        MatchResult where = null;

        if ("back".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            where = searcher.searchBackward();
        } else if ("fwd".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            where = searcher.searchForward();
        }

        textArea.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();

        if (where != null) {
            final int start = where.start();
            final int end   = where.end();
            // highligh result and scroll
            try {
            textArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, end, new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.yellow));
            } catch (BadLocationException excp) {}
            textArea.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, 0, scrollPane.getViewport().getWidth(), scrollPane.getViewport().getHeight()));
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() { textArea.setCaretPosition(start); }
            });
        } else if (where == null) {
            // no match, so let's wrap around
            if ("back".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                searcher.setSearchOffset( searcher.getText().length() -1 );
            } else if ("fwd".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
                searcher.setSearchOffset(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SearchTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new SearchTest());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following simple class to search backwards in java

```
public class ReverseMatcher {
   private final Matcher _matcher;
   private final Stack<MatchResult> _results = new Stack<>();

   public ReverseMatcher(Matcher matcher){
       _matcher = matcher;
   }

   public boolean find(){
       return find(_matcher.regionEnd());
   }

   public boolean find(int start){
       if (_results.size() > 0){
           _results.pop();
           return _results.size() > 0;
       }
       boolean res = false;
       while (_matcher.find()){            
           if (_matcher.end() > start)
               break;
           res = true;
           _results.push(_matcher.toMatchResult());
       }
       return res;
   }

   public String group(int group){
       return _results.peek().group(group);               
   }

   public String group(){
       return _results.peek().group();               
   }

   public int start(){
       return _results.peek().start();
   }    

   public int end(){
       return _results.peek().end();
   }
}
```

using:

```
String srcString = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
String pattern = "\\b[0-9]*\\b";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(srcString);
ReverseMatcher rm = new ReverseMatcher(m);
while (rm.find())
   System.out.print(rm.group() + " ");
```

output:  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

or

```
while (rm.find(9))
   System.out.print(rm.group() + " ");
```

output: 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

Is the search string strictly a regex (full, rich syntax?) Because if not, `for(int j = line; j >= 0 ; j--)`, reverse the line, reverse the match and search forward ;)

Comment: thanks for answering. clearly i'll need to search backwards in the lines. so, you solution is actually reverse the line + reverse the pattern + map back the match indices (start/end). (a) i'm wondering if there's a more efficient way... (b) reversing a regex pattern? i donnow...

Comment: Yes, as long as the pattern is `/some text/` it's okay, but if you search for `/^[0-9]+\s(\w+)/` or the like, this will obviously break. Another approach (that would not break likewise) would be to append a greedy `.*` in the beginning of the pattern, and truncate searched line at each found match, but finding the actual offset would become more problematic (the `.*` will always match at 0), so you'd have to substract length of your real match from matcher.end() Not very efficient again...

Answer (score 0):

If a previous match is something, that you have already matched going forward, then what about creating a list of matched positions while searching forward and then just use it to jump back instead of searching backward?