# How to search in reverse order using String or StringBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, string, search, stringbuilder

Can you please tell me how to search in reveres order (backward search) in Java?

I need to do same for searching in HTML file as text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355293/how-to-use-a-regex-to-search-backwards-effectively

Comment: You want load complete file at a time. if file is bigger you have to load content block by block.

Answer (score 11):

> ***[...] how to search in reveres order (backward search) in java?***

I assume you mean search for a string starting from the end.

For this task you can use [`String.lastIndexOf(str)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29). This will locate the *last* index of the substring `str`. If you want to keep searching from that point, you can add a second `fromIndex` argument.

The exact same methods exist for [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) as well.

Comment: ... and StringBuilder has the same thing too.

Comment: I was reading this question as he's looking for an efficient implementation of searching for a string, starting from the end of the string, (say a very long html file, where you're looking for a tag you know will be in the last ~20%, and you dont want to read the first 80 for no reason...)

Comment: Ok. I was reading it as he wanted to use String or StringBuilder, and I didn't find anything stating that it must be more efficient than the built in methods for those to classes.

Comment: My apologies I should be been more specific. Actually I want to find a html element (specifically dropdown) by its id and then capture its XML like part (ex. <select id="xyz" name="abc" > <option value="MyValue1">Option1</option> <option value="MyValue2">Option2</option> </select>. This XML like part will be usefull to run XPath query to find value attributes. So after finding id of this html element i have to search backward to find "<select" string. so that i can capture whole <select> </select> section. thanks all for your replies.

Comment: I would suggest you use an XML parser for this.

Comment: i guess u mean to say HTML parser. but I can't use third party libraries because of some restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

if want to search in file 
1. Open file in random access mode. 
2. go to end of file.
3. then search in string.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but this descriptions is of literally zero help to me. Step 1 is easy, step 2 is easy, step 3 makes no sense.