# Regex for formatting binary number with spaces every 4 characters, from right to left in Java

Tags: java, regex, binary

I'm writing a binary/decimal/hexadecimal converter for Android and am trying to format a String in Java with a regex that will add a space to every four characters from right to left.

This code works from left to right, but I am wondering if there is a way I can reverse it.

```
stringNum = stringNum.replaceAll("....", "$0 ");
```

Comment: Why don't you just reverse the string before operating on it?

Comment: That had crossed my mind, but I am not very familiar with Regex and I was not sure if there was an option to do this.

Comment: @A_Kiniyalocts I don't there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe instead of regex use `StringBuilder` like this

```
String data = "abcdefghij";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data);
for (int i = sb.length() - 4; i > 0; i -= 4)
    sb.insert(i, ' ');
data = sb.toString();
System.out.println(data);
```

output:

```
ab cdef ghij
```

Comment: I personally recommend the StringBuilder solution for problems of this nature.

Answer (score 2):

In `C#` you would do something like `Regex.Replace("1234567890", ".{4}", " $0", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)`.

**Unfortunately, in `Java` [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482145/297114).**

As Explossion Pills suggested in a comment, you could reverse the string, apply the  regex, and reverse it again.

Another solution could be to take the last `N` numbers from your string, where `N` is divisible by `4`. Then you can apply the replacement successfully, and concatenate the remaining part of the string at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "0123456789ABCDE";
// Use a StringBuffer to reverse the string
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str).reverse();
// This regex causes " " to occur before each instance of four characters
str = sb.toString().replaceAll("....", "$0 ");
// Reverse it again
str = (new StringBuffer(str)).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works great. Thanks for explaining it step by step too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best practice was to start from the beginning of the string to the end:

```
String inputString = "1234123412341234";
int j = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inputString);
for (int i = 4; i < kkm.getFiscalNumber().length(); i += 4) {
    sb.insert(i + j, ' ');
    j++;
}
String result = sb.toString(); // 1234 1234 1234 1234
```