# How do I strip patterns or words from the end of the string backwards?

Tags: python, xml, regex, string, right-to-left

I have a string like this:

```
<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar><foo>
```

I would like to strip the first 3 opening *and* the last 3 closing tags from the string. I do not know the tag names in advance.

I can strip the first 3 strings with `re.sub(r'<[^<>]+>', '', in_str, 3))`. How do I strip the closing tags? What should remain is:

```
<v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1>
```

I know I could maybe 'do it right', but I actually do not wish to do xml nor html parsing for my purpose, which is to aid myself visualizing the xml representation of some classes.

Instead, I realized that this problem is interesting. It seems I [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355293) simply search backwards with regex, ie. *right to left*. because that seems [unsupported](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-September/057148.html):

> If you  mean, find the right-most match of several (similar to the
>   rfind method of a string) then no, it is not directly supported. You
>   could use re.findall() and chose the last match but if the matches can
>   overlap this may not give the correct result.

But `.rstrip` is not good with words, and won't do patterns either.

I looked at [Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python) but I only wish to strip up to *3* tags.

What approach could be used here? Should I reverse the string (ugly in itself and due to the '<>'s). Do tokenization (why not parse, then?)? Or create static closing tags based on the left-to-right match?

Which strategy to follow to strip the patterns from the end of the string?

Comment: But parsing *is* the right answer to this problem. Why don't you want to do it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because it is too heavy-weight for *this* task. This is temporary visualization which will be thrown away. Parsing will do but it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest would be to use old-fashing string splitting and limiting the split:

```
in_str.split('>', 3)[-1].rsplit('<', 3)[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> in_str = '<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar><foo>'
>>> in_str.split('>', 3)[-1].rsplit('<', 3)[0]
'<v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1>'
```

[`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with a limit will split the string from the start or the end up to the limit times, letting you select the remainder unsplit.

Comment: Haha! Gotcha, seems I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: yeah, this is definitely the best solution for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got practically all the solution. `re` can't do backwards, but you can:

```
in_str = '<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar></foo>'
in_str = re.sub(r'<[^<>]+>', '', in_str, 3)
in_str = in_str[::-1]
print in_str
in_str = re.sub(r'>[^<>]+/<', '', in_str, 3)
in_str = in_str[::-1]

print in_str
<v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1>
```

Note the reversed regex for the reversed string, but then it goes back-to-front.

Of course, as mentioned, this is way easier with a proper parser:

```
in_str = '<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar></foo>'
from lxml.html import etree
ix = etree.fromstring(in_str)
print etree.tostring(ix[0][0][0])
<v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1>
```

Comment: +1 Nice back-pattern and the notation for the string reversing. It will solve reverse-matching. Still, for this specific case, Martijn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22478982/611007) beats it with the simplicity. I think adding the elementTree example makes this the best complementary reference answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into regular expressions and use one such pattern to use a split

http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.regex.split

Comment: hm, yeah, maybe I could split based on the pattern for the last 3 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment, but will give it as an answer.

`in_str.split('>', 3)[-1].rsplit('<', 3)[0]` will work for the given example 
`<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar></foo>`, but not for 
`<foo><bar><k2><v1>aaa<b>bbb</b>ccc</v1></k2></bar></foo><another>test</another>`. 
You just should be aware of this.

To solve the counter example provided by me, you will have to track state (or count) of tags and evaluate that you match the correct pairs.

Comment: yes, thanks! `<another>test</another>` is not my case. In my case the format is as in my example. It would constitute just a common corner case to something for what the general answer is indeed parsing. However I was mainly interested in the right-to-left string manipulation aspect.